# Passing parameter without parameter name

Tags: perl, parameters, cgi

I am trying to pass a parameter after string query. 
I know that I can pass parameter with a name to cgi, for example I can pass a name parameter by doing `www.mypage.com/index.html?name=Sae` 
and retrieve it using CGI `my $name = q->param('name')`

But is there a way to pass parameters without parameter name?
For example if I want to pass the `Sae` part in `www.mypage.com/index.html?Sae`

is there any way to do this? any programming language is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried inspecting `param` after calling a CGI script with only `?Sae`?

In debug mode, it seems to assign the value to the `keywords` key:

```
echo Sae | perl -MCGI=:debug -E '
    $q=CGI->new;
    say "$_: ", scalar $q->param($_) for $q->param'

(offline mode: enter name=value pairs on standard input; press ^D or ^Z when done)
keywords: Sae
```

`$q->keywords` seems to work, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
`$q->keywords` doesn't work, but `$q->param('keywords')` works like charm